# Wordpress - замена картинки в шапке через свой плагин

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Использую плагин GeoIP Detect.
Есть функция, но она работает с заголовком записи:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title ) {
    $geoip = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    $country = $geoip->raw[ 'country' ][ 'iso_code' ];
        if ( 'US' !== $country ) {
        $title = str_replace( 'soccer', 'football', $country );
    }

    return $title;

});
```

Использую ее в своем плагине(плагин устанавливается и работает нормально). Как с помощью данной функции (плагина GeoIP Detect) переписывать картинку в шапке на другую, в зависимости от значения $country ? Не могу пока разобраться как обратится к картинке в шапке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать это, нужно видеть код вашего сайта / темы целиком, и проанализировать его на предмет хуков, что скорее всего выйдет за рамки обычного вопроса на `SO`.

В `WP` есть два варианта хуков, для `action` и для `filter`. Различие между ними простое - первые добавляют некую `callback` функцию в некое место в коде, которая выполняет еще некий код, второе всего лишь позволяет видоизменить то, что получит браузер пользователя. Иногда это практически одно и то же, но чтобы было более понятно, рассмотрим простые примеры:

`action`: в момент обращения к базе данных нам нужно ввести дополнительную проверку на валидность вносимых данных. Мы через `do_action()` помечаем некое место в коде, где происходит обращение к базе данных, после чего через `add_action()` добавляем в это место функцию, которая произведет нужные нам действия.

`filter`:  в момент вывода "подвала" сайта нам нужно изменить класс у селектора `<footer>`. Мы через `apply_filters()` помечаем некое место в коде (некую переменную, содержащую `html`-код нашего `<footer>`), где происходит вывод "подвала", после чего через `add_filter()` добавляем в это место функцию, которая найдет в коде "подвала" селектор `<footer>` и добавит ему нужный нам класс.

Именно это и происходит у вас в предоставленном коде - добавляется фильтр на ранее созданный через `add_filters()` хук `the_title`, который сначала определяется, какой у нас собственно город посетителя, а потом, если мы не в США, видоизменяет наш `title`, возвращая его в новом виде (заменяет везде `soccer` на `football`).

Теперь вы наверняка сможете попробовать найти место в коде, где у вас выводится ваша картинка в хедере, посмотреть, есть ли для значения ее атрибута `src` некий фильтр (хотя, возможно, что фильтр будет на весь хедер целиком, или еще как-либо, все зависит от фантазии создателя шаблона сайта), и если есть - просто добавить некий фильтр к этому хуку, а если нет - создать хук самостоятельно, после чего написать, подобную предоставленной вами, `callback`-функцию, которая будет возвращать в хук (а он - в переменную, к которой он привязан) либо одну, либо другую версию картинки.

Comment: Спасибо Станислав. Место в коде найти это не проблема, где картинка выводится. У меня трудности с определением хуков, т.к я не силен в Wordpress. Мне кажется, что замену картинки в данном случае можно выполнить только через замену слоя , в котормо выводится картинка.

Comment: Либо, если я правильно понял, то можно сделать свой хук кастомный и по нему уже выдергивать.

Comment: @DimaKuzmin верно, в целом ничто не мешает вам сделать это.

Comment: При этом я хочу сказать, что хука на именно картинку у вас наверняка не найдется, слишком мал шанс, что создатель шаблона реализовал его, так как с одной стороны это чисто ваша задача, менять картинку в зависимости от условий, а с другой стороны, если уж создатель темы и делал бы это, то вынес бы в настройки шаблона. Делать не управляемый пользователем фильтр есть смысл как раз для приведенных вами задач, где в любом случае надо заменить соккер на футбол. Про какой-то уже существ. хук на больший слой - аналогично, вряд ли был смысл это делать, я написал про эту возможность скорее для полноты